# Fazer com que o SonarQube com o OpenCover ignorarem algumas classes C#

Tags: c#, .net

É possível configurar o SonarQube com o OpenCover para ignorar algumas classes do meu projeto .NET?

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona a flag `-filter` ao comando de execucao do OpenCover para excluir tipos que pertencem a um namespace `MyNamespace`:

```
-filter:"+[*]* -[NomeDaAssembly]MyNamespace.*"
```

Nao tenho a certeza, mas acho que tambem se pode excluir ficheiros especificos de uma forma semelhante:

```
-filter:"+[*]* -[NomeDaAssembly]MyNamespace.MySpecificClass.cs"
```

Comment: Eu não chamo diretamente o OpenCover, tudo é feito pelo Sonar, de acordo com o arquivo sonar-project.properties. Tem como colocar esses comando "filter" no sonar-project.properties? Pela documentação do sonar, aparentemente, só dá pra excluir a nível de projeto...